# android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions is unresolved

Tags: android, eclipse

i'm working on an android app in eclipse (version 3.6.2) & i just added the following:
           import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;

But i get an error ... the import cannot be resolved ...

however these omports all DO get resolved:
           import android.webkit.WebView;
           import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
           import android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler;
           import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
           import android.webkit.WebSettings;

can someone tell my why this 1 is unresolved & what i can do to get it to resolve?

thanks

& the answer is :

i needed to upgrade the sdk i was using .. from level 3 to level 5 ...

question answered .. 
thanks

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem, and the code worked when

`public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
     callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
}`

was changed to

`public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
     callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
}`

The only subtle difference is using `android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions` in place of `GeolocationPermissions`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Eclipse Helios Service Release 2. Here is mine... it is built for Android 2.1 and it works fine...

```
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

/* ... your other stuff here ... */

WebView webview1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

/*... more other stuff here ...*/

webview1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webview1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
});

webview1.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath("/data/data/<my-app>");
```

And dont forget to add the following to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Hope it helps!